# Cookie “CookieName” has been rejected because there is already an HTTP-Only cookie but script tried to store a new one

Tags: javascript, cookies

```
 var CookieName = "TestCookie";
  document.cookie = "CookieName=Cheecker; path =/; httponly=false;samesite=None;secure=true;"
     alert(document.cookie);
  if (document.cookie.indexOf(CookieName) == -1) {
    console.log("Cookies are required to use shopping carts.");
  }

  if (document.cookie.indexOf(CookieName) != -1) {
    console.log(
      "Thank you for enabling Third-Party cookies we only using it for our shopping carts"
    );
  }
```

I want to check if Third-party cookies are enabled in the user browser

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've got a few questions wrapped up here.  I'll answer the one you implied with your title: why are you getting the '`Cookie "CookieName" has been rejected...`' error?

There are two reasons, both of which can be confirmed on Mozilla's "[Using HTTP Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Creating_cookies)" page, in the 'Creating Cookies' section:

**First:**
HttpOnly is a flag, not a variable.  You have `httponly=false;` in your cookie setting call.  It should just be `HttpOnly;`, and incidentally the same applies for `Secure;`.  Example:

```
document.cookie = "CookieName=Cheecker; path =/; HttpOnly; samesite=None; Secure;"
```

**Second:**
`HttpOnly` is a setting that restricts cookies to HTTP calls only.  They can't be accessed by JavaScript... and so they can't be set by JavaScript, either.  From Mozilla's page:

```
Cookies created via JavaScript cannot include the HttpOnly flag.
```

So.  I can't speak to how to figure out whether third-party cookies are set in the user's browser, but you'll resolve your error by removing the `HttpOnly` flag from your cookie creation call.